# ssh - 'connection reset by peer' - windows

Tags: windows, git, bash, ssh

I am running ssh via git bash in a windows environment.  I had everything working fine but now (a few days later) when I try to connect to bitbucket I get the message: `ssh-exchange_identification: read: connection reset by peer.`

The full log looks like this:

```
$ ssh -Tvvv -p 443 git@altssh.bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to altssh.bitbucket.org [131.103.20.174] port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/c/Documents and Settings/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /c/Documents and Settings/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Documents and Settings/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Documents and Settings/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Documents and Settings/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Documents and Settings/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Documents and Settings/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Documents and Settings/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Documents and Settings/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
```

ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

My issue is exactly like [bibucket ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690101/bibucket-ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer) **except**

1) I can confirm that my company is not inspecting and blocking packets over port 443 (though they **are** blocking port 22 which is why I am going over 443 to begin with)

2) I can confirm the issue is not with the bitbucket servers - other people on my team can get in just fine

As stated above, this was working just fine before.  I did erase all my keys and started over but to no avail.

Help!  I've been banging my head on this for two days now...

**Updated** -- added more verbose log

Comment: 1) Please post a verbose log with `-vvv` 2) Check what is content of your configuration files for client.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it was faulty logic to think that just because other members on my team had access that ***I*** wasn't being blocked.  I was/am.

Comment: Hi there, so how did you get about it?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when submitting content to my own repository on github. At present, the change is pushed to the repository using http interface, but ssh still does not work

> kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host Connection closed by 20.205.243.166 port 22 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33006255)